# Lazy Parameter Evaluation

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm adding a bit amount of tracing and debugging code into a class that I'm refactoring.

I have a `Trace` object which has some filtering properties and methods `bool CanTrace(Level, , TracePropertyList = no_additional_properties)` and `bool Trace(Level, string, TracePropertyList = no_additional_properties)`.

There are already many places in the code where this trace object is used, and the string argument to the `Trace` method is usually some expression that I would like to avoid evaluating if I'm not going to end up outputting tracing info.

Repeating the chunk of code

```
if(trace.CanTrace(LEVEL_INFO, some_props))
  trace.Trace(LEVEL_INFO, consume_time().to_str(), some_props);
```

is ugly, and I'd like something shorter.

I was thinking about the macros

```
#define TRACE_WITH_PROPS(LEVEL,STRING,PROPS) //...
```

and

```
#define TRACE(LEVEL,STRING) //...
```

Is there a better way to do this? Possibly with templates or C++11? I don't like hiding things from the compiler with defines, and I'm doing my best to remove some macros elsewhere in this codebase.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.templog.org, which employs template meta-programming for logging to defer parameter evaluation. I think it hasn't been worked on for a while, but it does exactly what you want and it does it well. If nothing else, you could use it as a starting point.

Comment: Macros don't hide things from the compiler, they hide things from the programmer. :)

Comment: There are 2 logging libraries for boost: [boost.log](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/index.html) is provisionally accepted into boost (and improved to be accepted definitively), [boost.logging](http://torjo.com/log2/index.html) lost the battle and seems to be unmaintained now. They are both designed for performace in mind, including no evaluation when logging is not done. It has other features as well, like handling multi-threading, sending logs to different places, exception safety, and so on.

Answer (score 6):

In C++11, you can use closure. You'd have something like:

```
trace.Trace(LEVEL_INFO, [&](){ return format("x is %i") % ExpensiveWayToGetX(y, z); }, some_props);
```

In C++03, you can use the boost.lambda hack for similar effect.

However, having a macro wrapping the `if(trace.CanTrace(...)) trace.Trace(...)` is still slightly more efficient, because it doesn't even initialize the object with all the references the closure will need if tracing is not on. I suggest combining the macro with the stream interface, so you'd have

```
#define TRACE(level, some_props) \
    if(!trace.CanTrace(level, some_props)) 0; \
        else trace.Trace(level, some_props)
```

and call it like

```
TRACE(LEVEL_INFO, some_props) << "x is " << ExpensiveWayToGetX(y, z);
```

or define `operator()` instead of `operator<<` and for printf-style formatting:

```
TRACE(LEVEL_INFO, some_props)("x is %i", ExpensiveWayToGetX(y, z));
```

The if *not* enabled, than 0, else actually trace is there so that it does not eat the else if you ever write:

```
if(IsSomethingWrong())
    TRACE(LEVEL_WARNING, some_props) << WhatIsWrong() << " is wrong";
else
    DoSomething();
```

(without else in the macro, the else after it would go to the if inside the macro, but with that else, it will parse correctly)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid string processing, lambdas are a good solution as in the answer by Johannes Schaub. If your compiler doesn't support lambdas yet then you could do it like this with no C++0x features and no macroes:

```
doTrace(LEVEL_INFO, some_props) << "Value of i is " << i;
```

doTrace would return a temporary object with a virtual operator<<. If no tracing is to be performed, then return an object whose operator<< does nothing. Otherwise return an object whose operator<< does what you want. The destructor of the temporary object can signal that the string being outputted is done. Now destructors shouldn't throw, so if the final processing of the trace event can throw an exception, then you may need to include an end-of-event overload of operator<<

This solution causes several virtual function calls even when no tracing is done, so it is less efficient than "if(tracing) ...". That should only really matter in performance critical loops where you probably want to avoid doing tracing anyway. In any case you could revert to checking tracing with an if in those cases or when the logic for doing the tracing is more complicated than comfortably fits in a sequence of <<'s.

Comment: AFAIK consume_time().to_str() is going to be evaluated here

Comment: @yi_H Yep, if you want to avoid the string processing with this method, then all that string processing has to happen through the stream object. So you would either add an overload of to_str that takes the stream object, or you would add an overload of operator<< on the stream object for the type that you would otherwise call to_str on.

Comment: @Bjarke: That still does not solve the case of `doTrace(LEVEL_INFO, some_props) << "Value of x is " << DamnExpensiveCallToGetX(y, z)`. That does not happen too often, but when it does, you do want the logger to have solution for it.

Comment: @Jan Hudec Yes, that is an issue. To solve it, either move the DamnExpensiveCallToGetX() into a virtual operator<< or revert to using if (tracing) {...}. The idea is for this solution to solve the common case conveniently, and then you fall back to the less convenient methods when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely vouch for having well defined set of macros over same code appearing umpteen times. Just define set of macros having multiple names, with different *levels* - and on top of them have a macro that will have `if-else`, `template magic`, `assertions`, `static-asserts`, `static-type-checking`, more of `macro-abuse` and what not.

Using macros would also allow you to conditionally include/exclude some part (like exclusion of static-asserts, asserts etc). Initially it would be hard to write up macros, adapt to them, find compiler/runtime bugs related with them, but they will swoosh away with the feature-rich facilities they would provide in later stages of coding, bug-detection and development.

Draw macros carefully!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know is are template-functions the best place to ensure that the compiler tries to optimize stuff away. So, I would hope that something like the following could make the compiler optimize the creation of the `message` out, if you instantiate `Trace_<false> trace;`

This should do the trick, and give you the idea:

```
template<bool yesno> struct Trace_ {};
template<> struct Trace_<false> {
    void operator()(const string &) const {}
};
template<> struct Trace_<true> {
   void operator()(const string &message) const {
      clog << message << endl;
   }
};

//Trace_<true> trace;
Trace_<false> trace;

int main() {
    trace("a message");
}
```

Somehow I think create in instance `trace` is not the best idea. Maybe one can to this with free function-templates only, or a static member function (`operator()` can not be static)?

Comment: Whether the trace is on or off is determined at run time. The template solution in this form only allows compile time enable/disable.

Comment: Even with compile-time, the arguments will still be evaluated. If you write `trace("x is ", DamnExpensiveCallToGetX(y, z))`, the `DamnExpensiveCallToGetX` function will be called even if tracing is turned off. Even if it is turned off at compile-time, it will still call it, because the compiler can't be sure it does not have any significant side-effects (assuming it's not inlineable, but damn expensive calls usually are not).

Comment: hmm, right. would a future/promise via `async(std::launch::[a]sync, DamnExpensive())` would help? But that must be done at the calling-place and that would be DamnAnnoying :-)

Comment: @towi: No. That would still run the function, just in separate thread. You need to create a closure instead (either using C++11 lambda syntax or using boost's bind). Still has to be done at the calling place, so it's still just as annoying.

Answer (score 0):

(because this answer is a complete different approach, I separate it from my other one, where I misunderstood the question)

At **runtime** you want to prevent the a big-string-merge expression is being executed? Hmm... difficult. I think you could use **perfect forwarding of variadic template arguments** just as a rough idea (C++0x'ish pseudocode):

```
template<typename MSGS...>
void trace(const MSGS... &&msgs) {
    if(IS_TRACE) {
        doTrace( std::forward<MSGS...>(msgs) );
    }
}

void func() {
    trace("A String", 52, image, matrix, "whatver doTrace can handle");
}
```

`doTrace` can then be a recursive **variadic-template** function (like the `printf`  in [Bjarne Stroutrups FAQs:Variadic Templates](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html)). The `&&` and `forward` should ensure that the arguments are not touched until they arrive at `doTrace`. So, you should have only one call with a couple of arguments and the `if(IS_TRACE)`-test when you don't want to trace anything.

If you like the idea, I will program it out -- just holler!

Comment: The same problem as all the other solutions. The case of `trace("x is ", DamnExpensiveCallToGetX(y, z))`. When that happens, you want to have some solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is my quick solution.

```
class Logger
{
public:
    Logger():m_lvl(0){;}
    void level(int i){m_lvl=i;}
    void log(int level, std::function<std::string(void)> fun)
    {
        if (level <= m_lvl)
        {
            std::cout << fun() << std::endl;
        }
    }
private:
    int m_lvl;
};
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo():m_a(3), m_b(5){;}
    void run()
    {
        Logger l;
        int c = m_b;
        std::cout << "Running" <<std::endl;
        auto lambda = [&](int my, int log)->std::string {
            std::cout <<"Consume while logging set to "<< log << " and my message level is "<< my << std::endl;
            return (std::string(this->m_a, 'a') + std::string(c, 'c'));
        };
        // The bind/lambda is just to show the different levels
        l.log(0, [=]{return lambda(0, 0);} );
        l.log(1, [=]{return lambda(1, 0);} );
        l.level(5);
        l.log(1, [=]{return lambda(1, 5);});
    }
private:
    int m_a, m_b;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Output

> Running
>   Consume while logging set to 0 and my message level is 0
>   aaaccccc
>   Consume while logging set to 5 and my message level is 1
>   aaaccccc

We didn't consume time outputting/computing a level 1 message when set to log level 0.